# Design pattern with methods that return modified parent

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

Lets say I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Data
{
    public Data()
    {
       // Stuff
    }

    public void Process1()
    {
       // Stuff
    }

    public void Process2()
    {
       // Stuff
    }
}
```

I have several options for how to use it. The most common one is the following:

```
var data = new Data();
data.Process1();
data.Process2();
```

One alternative that I like to use requires me to modify the class:

```
class Data
{
    public Data()
    {
       // Stuff
    }

    public Data Process1()
    {
       // Stuff
       return this;
    }

    public Data Process2()
    {
       // Stuff
       return this;
    }
}
```

Then I can use it like so:

```
var data = new Data().Process1().Process2();
```

To which design pattern, if any, does this style of writing classes belong?

Comment: It is called [Fluent Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)

Comment: Imho it is not a GOF Design Pattern, it's more of simple Method chaining...

Comment: @Fabjan Makes for really neat syntax though.

Comment: Note that it also alows: `new Data().Process1().Process2().Process1().Process2().Process1().Process2().Process1().Process2().Process1().Process2().Process1().Process2().Process1().Process2().Process1().Process2();` etc... indefinite number of times ? I'd use it carefully...

Comment: @Fabjan What prevents you from doing the same using normal syntax? `var data = new Data(); data.Process1(); data.Process2(); data.Process1(); data.Process2(); // etc`. Any and all design patterns must be used responsibly in order to be effective.

Comment: @stybl Nothing, but it is not the same as calling methods in chain, sometimes it works good, and sometimes bad - depending on specific scenario...

Comment: The only drawback is the increase of the reference count for each call

Comment: @Fabjan one could return different interfaces to restrict this.

Comment: Take a look at Decorator pattern.

Comment: A method on a fluent interface should, in my opinion, return a new instance of the source object with the state updated by that method. Otherwise it's easy to write misleading code. LINQ does it properly - calling `.Where`, for example, on an enumerable doesn't alter the enumerable but instead returns a new one. That's the best way to write a fluent interface. When you see `return this;` I would consider it code smell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A method on a fluent interface should, in my opinion, return a new instance of the source object with the state updated by that method. Otherwise it's easy to write misleading code.

Take this code for example:

```
public class Data
{
    public double Value { get; private set; }
    public Data(double value) { this.Value = value; }

    public Data Times2Add1()
    {
        this.Value = this.Value * 2.0 + 1.0;
        return this;
    }

    public Data Divide3()
    {
        this.Value = this.Value / 3.0;
        return this;
    }
}
```

If I run this:

```
var x = new Data(5);
var y = x.Times2Add1();
var z = x.Divide3();

Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
Console.WriteLine(y.Value);
Console.WriteLine(z.Value);
```

I get:

```
3.66666666666667
3.66666666666667
3.66666666666667
```

However, if I write it like this:

```
public class Data
{
    public double Value { get; private set; }
    public Data(double value) { this.Value = value; }

    public Data Times2Add1()
    {
        return new Data(this.Value * 2.0 + 1.0);
    }

    public Data Divide3()
    {
        return new Data(this.Value / 3.0);
    }
}
```

The results are

```
5
11
1.66666666666667
```

And of course I can write `var w = x.Times2Add1().Divide3();` which gives me the `3.66666666666667` I got above, but this time it makes more sense to me. It becomes testable robust code.

LINQ does it properly - calling `.Where`, for example, on an enumerable doesn't alter the enumerable but instead returns a new one. That's the best way to write a fluent interface.

When you see `return this;`, even though that's a fluent interface, I would consider it code smell.

Comment: If you want to do it like LINQ you have to wrap the source instance with a wrapper class. Beyond this I agree with you

Comment: @SirRufo - Yes, you're right, but only if you expect deferred execution.

Comment: You've given a very simple example. In a large class with many properties, one would have to copy each and every one of them into the new instance. Hardly an elegant solution imo. Unless there is something I'm missing.

Comment: @stybl - It depends on how you define *elegant*. A solution without side-effects is more elegant in my mind. Typically when I've had an object with a lot of properties I've implemented a private clone method that allows the fluent interface to easily copy a lot of properties and then I just update whatever values need to change. It becomes fairly straight forward.

Comment: A [fluent interface](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) is more than just method chaining. Every occurrence of `return this` is not necessarily a fluent interface.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the builder pattern [here](http://www.dofactory.com/net/builder-design-pattern), it is used in .net core startup class to create the app´s configuration via ConfigurationBuilder object, and they use the chained calls:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", 
        optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", 
        optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```